# Is there is any analogue of mean value theorem for integral when the range is whole $R$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Is there is any analogue of mean value theorem for integral of a continuous function when the range of the integral is whole real line?

**By MVT:** if a function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$, where $a < b$, and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b),$ then there exists a point $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that
$\int_a^bf(x)dx=(b-a)f(c)$.

**Now my question is:** Is there any Theorem like MVT for$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx$?

Thanks

Comment: No, there are such theorems. You can say that $\lim_{T\to\infty} \frac1T\int_0^T f(x)\,dx$ (if it exists) is a mean $\bar f$ of function $f$ and nothing more. But there is a point $c$ such that $\bar f = f(c)$.

Comment: @Michael what do you mean by "no, there are"? Are there or aren't there?

Comment: @GFauxPas, it was a typo, sorry. "There are no such theorems"

Comment: Your last sentence is not so useful. Let $f(c)\ne 0$; so, $V = \frac{1}{f(c)}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\,dx$

Comment: @Michael Galuza . Thanks, I got your point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that $f$ is bounded, and that $q:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$ is a weight function such that $\int_{\mathbb R}q(x)\>{\rm d}x=1$. Then there is a $c\in{\mathbb R}$ such that
$$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\>q(x)\>{\rm d}x= f(c)\ .$$
The proof, using $m:=\inf_{x\in{\mathbb R}} f(x)$ and $M:=\sup_{x\in{\mathbb R}} f(x)$, is the same as for the  MVT for finite intervals.

Comment: Thank you. I have proved the statement using the given hints.